# python - why this output of list?

Tags: python

I want to understand what `A[A[i]]` means in this code:

```
A = [1,4,2,0,3]
temp = A[0]

for i in range(len(A)-1):
    A[i] = A[i+1]

A[len(A)-1] = temp

for i in range (len(A)):
    print(A[A[i]], end ="" )
```

output :

```
10432
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I know the output but I need to understand how did we get it, specially this part:

`print(A[A[i]], end ="" )`

what does `A[A[i]]` mean?

Comment: It’s just using the value of A[i] as an index into A. Not a normal thing to do. What’s this code supposed to be doing?

Comment: Next time you could try to run and go through each step in this great platform - https://pythontutor.com/

Comment: Even understanding what each operation is doing, I'm absolutely bewildered why someone wrote it, or what they were ultimately hoping to accomplish. Is this some sort of assignment, where the only point is to have you interpret what's going on?

Comment: I have an exam, and this was one of the questions that I didn't understand. 
@CrazyChucky and bob
Thank you Daniel Hao

Comment: Even as an assignment, it seems odd... the part that shifts the list (everything after the list definition and before the final `for` loop) could've been simply `A.append(A.pop(0))`. Not to mention that all-capital variable names are conventionally used for constants. I wonder about the habits this class is teaching.

Comment: @CrazyChucky I’m taking Design and technology exam, a part of it is programming, that was a question there, all of it is MCQs, but I didn’t understand it, so I asked for help, its my first time studying python.

Comment: I was critiquing the class, not you. I'm saying that, based on this assignment, I'm not sure your teacher is teaching very well.

Answer (score 0):

`A[A[i]]` is just the element of `A` with index `A[i]`. For example, if you have `A = [1, 2]`, `A[A[i]] = 2` if `i = 0` because `A[0] = 1` so `A[A[0]] = A[1] = 2`.

And for your information, `end=""` just means that python won't skip a line after printing the value.

Answer (score 0):

All the elements of: `A = [1,4,2,0,3]` are also, by coincidence valid indexes into `A`.

Note that the list `A` has 5 elements and each element is in the range `0..4`.

This means that for any `A[i]` where `i` is a valid index retrieves one of the values, which itself is a valid index.

So, looking at the last two lines:

```py
for i in range (len(A)):
    print(A[A[i]], end ="" )
```

we can see that the `for` loop causes `i` to be a valid index each time round, therefore `A[i]` is a valid index, therefore `A[A[i]]` returns one of the values from `A`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking from your time to answer, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

After Evaluating the following piece of code:

```
A=[1,4,2,0,3]
temp = A[0]
for i in range(len(A)-1):
    A[i] = A[i+1]
A[len(A)-1] = temp
```

we get the updated array: A=[4,2,0,3,1]
Now the remaining piece of code can be evaluated as:

1. for i=0 we have A[A[0]]=A[4]=1;
2. for i=1 we have A[A[1]]=A[2]=0;
3. for i=2 we have A[A[2]]=A[0]=4;
4. for i=3 we have A[A[3]]=A[3]=3;
5. for i=4 we have A[A[4]]=A[1]=2;

As format is given as => end=""
the result is printed as : 10432

Comment: Thank you so much, your detailed explanation helped me a lot.
I appreciate your efforts.